# AudioRecord and MediaRecorder Android parallele

Tags: android, time, mediarecorder, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

I have to use in my application and audiorecord MediaRecorder same time. One register my scripts and the other for displaying the sound input with the amplitudes of the input signal. My application crash when I use simultaneously but independently it works fine. So do you have a solution that I can use at the same time???

```
Trace logCat :
10-16 22:02:08.675: E/MediaRecorder(9007): start failed: -1
10-16 22:02:08.675: W/System.err(9007): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
10-16 22:02:08.675: W/System.err(9007):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
10-16 22:02:08.675: W/System.err(9007):     at com.ax.audio_recorder.viewlvlmicro.SoundMeter.start(SoundMeter.java:40)
10-16 22:02:08.675: W/System.err(9007):     at com.ax.audio_record.MainActivity.start(MainActivity.java:177)
10-16 22:02:08.675: W/System.err(9007):     at com.ax.audio_record.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:173)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at com.ax.audio_record.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:154)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
10-16 22:02:08.680: W/System.err(9007):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many platforms that Android devices are based on limit the number of open audio input streams to 1, which is causing an exception when you try to create another one before closing the first.

You could record raw PCM with an AudioRecord and use that data both for writing it to a file (if that's what you mean by "register my scripts") and as input for your visualizer. The downside is that if you want to save the audio compressed (e.g. mp3) you'll need to handle the encoding yourself in your app.

Comment: I record my audio mp3 source there is no way to use MediaRecorder audiorecord and at the same time? Here I use the microphone as audio source

Comment: It might be possible on some phones (I can't say for sure since I'm not familiar with the modifications that every vendor do in the audio HAL). What I can say is that there are phones where it won't work, so your app will fail on some phones if you use your current solution.

Comment: ok thank you for your reply, I visualize better the problems.

With audiorecord how I can retrieve the signal amplitude. Because in reality it is its the problem I encounter now.

Comment: If you record 16-bit PCM you'll get samples that are signed shorts, so the range is -32768..+32767.

Comment: Each sample represents the amplitude of the waveform at that point in time, as a value between -32768 and +32767.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but you would not have an example of code ... because AudioRecord.getSampleRate () returns not the amplitude of the sound ...

Comment: But the buffer that gets filled out by AudioRecord.read() will contain the samples, i.e. the signal amplitude at each point in time where the signal was sampled.

Comment: AudioRecord.read ():> the number of bytes that were read or or ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION if the object wasn't properly initialized, or ERROR_BAD_VALUE if the parameters don't resolve to valid data and indexes. The number of bytes will not exceed sizeInBytes. How get amplitude of signal with ? please

Comment: AudioRecord.read() will fill the buffer you pass to it with the audio samples.

Comment: @Michael hi, i am using audiorecord and i send the buffer for processing fft, its giving me an issue, can we disscuss that ?